# Auto-redirection problem in the Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

**My code, it has a redirection problem for the Drawer Navigator screens, when opening the Drawer through the BottomTabNavitor("Mais"). How can i solve this?**

**This is where my Drawer and Bottom tab are:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, SafeAreaView, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
 
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


const ActivityIndicatorElement = () => {
  //making a view to show to while loading the webpage
  return (
    <ActivityIndicator
       color="#009688"
       size="large"
       style={styles.activityIndicatorStyle}
    />
  );
}

  const UrlGoAction = ({ url }) => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView  sharedCookiesEnabled={true} source={{ uri: url }}
          renderLoading={ActivityIndicatorElement}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          //For the Cache
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          //Want to show the view or not
          startInLoadingState={true}
        />
      </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };


export default function FisioBottomBar() {

    return (
        <Tab.Navigator 
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
              let iconName;
              if (route.name === 'Notícias') {
                iconName = 'newspaper';
              } else if (route.name === 'Calendário') {
                iconName = 'calendar';
              } else if (route.name === 'Fisioterapeutas') {
                iconName = 'badge-account';
              }
              else if (route.name === 'Indicadores') {
                iconName = 'chart-bar';
              }
              else if (route.name === 'Mais') {
                iconName = 'dots-horizontal';
              }
              return <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} color={color} size={size} />;
            },               
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000BAD',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'white',            
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor:"#0073AA",
              color: 'white',
            },                    
            headerShown:false
          })}
        >         
          <Tab.Screen name="Notícias"  >
            {() => <UrlGoAction url="https://staging.ordemdosfisioterapeutas.pt/category/noticias/?hideinapp=true" />}
          </Tab.Screen>   
          <Tab.Screen name="Calendário"  >
            {() => <UrlGoAction url="https://staging.ordemdosfisioterapeutas.pt/eventos/?hideinapp=true" />}
          </Tab.Screen>   
          <Tab.Screen name="Fisioterapeutas"  >
            {() => <UrlGoAction url="https://staging.ordemdosfisioterapeutas.pt/encontre-um-fisioterapeuta?hideinapp=true" />}
          </Tab.Screen>   
          <Tab.Screen name="Indicadores"  >
            {() => <UrlGoAction url="https://staging.ordemdosfisioterapeutas.pt/dados-demograficos-dos-membros?hideinapp=true" />}
          </Tab.Screen>                         
          <Tab.Screen
          name="Mais"
          options={{
            tabBarButton: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigationRef.current?.navigate('DrawerScreen')}
                style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="dots-horizontal" color="white" size={30} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
          }}
        />                       
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );    
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView style={{flex: 1, top: 0, bottom: 0, backgroundColor: '#FDFFFF'}} {...props}>
      
      <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>
       <Image source={require('../assets/logo.png')} style={{width: 192, height: 127}} />
       <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('AreaReservada',{screen: 'AreaReservadaScreen'})}
        }
    >


     <Text style={styles.areaReservada}>Área reservada</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Notícias"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('NoticiasDrawer')}
        icon={({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="newspaper" color={color} size={size} />
        )}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Calendário"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('CalendarioDrawer')}
        icon={({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar" color={color} size={size} />
        )}
      />     
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}




const DrawerNavigator = () => (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerPosition="right"        
      screenOptions={{drawerPosition:'right',headerShown:false,drawerStyle: {
         height:'100%',
      },}}
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
     <Drawer.Screen name="NoticiasDrawer" options={{headerShown: false}} >
        {() => <UrlGoAction url="https://staging.ordemdosfisioterapeutas.pt/category/noticias/?hideinapp=true" />}
     </Drawer.Screen>
     <Drawer.Screen name="CalendarioDrawer" options={{headerShown: false}} >
        {() => <UrlGoAction url="https://staging.ordemdosfisioterapeutas.pt/eventos/?hideinapp=true" />}
     </Drawer.Screen>
     <Drawer.Screen name="AreaReservada" options={{headerShown: false}} >
        {() => <UrlGoAction url="https://portal-qa.ordemdosfisioterapeutas.pt/?hideInApp=true" />}
     </Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>      
);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'white'
  },
  activityIndicatorStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    marginTop: 'auto',
    marginBottom: 'auto',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    padding: 0,
    top: -20,
    backgroundColor:"white",
    borderBottomColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  drawerHeaderText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  areaReservada:{
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: '#0073AA',
    color: "white",
    width:150,
    height:30,
    marginBottom:10,
    marginTop: -15,
    padding:5,
  },
});
```

**I tried to create a touchable Opacity to open the drawer, and prevet  redirection, but dont work it.**

**I thing i dont applied the navigation correctly.**